# Hash table & TextBox

Tags: powershell

I have the TextBox

```
$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1)
.
.
$x = $textBox.Text
```

and want to include my hash table in a way the input of the TextBox corresponds to values in it.

For example :

```
$hash = @{
A1 = "Stick"
A2 = "Leaf"
A3 = "Tree"
}
```

When I type A1 into the TextBox I want it to output 'stick'.

Previously, I used

```
do {
    $computer = $null
    $choice = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Type the name of a computer','Test')
    # exit the loop if the user cancels the box or clicks OK with an emty value
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($choice)) { break }
    
    $computer = $hash[$choice]
} until ($computer)
```

But I haven't figured out how to implement
$choice into the script to output it correctly

help much needed

Comment: I'm not clear on your goal.  You said "Previously, I used" and introduce code using InputBox, but above that you are talking about using a textbox.  Initially I thought you were trying to merge both sets of code, but now I'm thinking you are trying to replace the InputBox code with a Form that has a TextBox. Could you clarify your goal?

Comment: @Darin very sorry for not explaining it properly. Yes, I want to replace the InputBox with a TextBox. My goal is to make the TextBox choose values from to the has table, just like the InputBox. My issue being that I don't know how to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out yesterday. The answer to my problem was:

```
  $hash = @{
    A1 = "Stick"
    A2 = "Leaf"
    A3 = "Tree"
    }
   

$textBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1)
.
.

$x = $hash[$textBox1.Text]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was a fun project.  Used to do a lot in C# forms, and still new to forms in PowerShell - but I've been itching for an excuse.

I found this [Custom Input Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-5.1) from Microsoft, but then found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60810587/4190564) by rokumaru.  The answer given by rokumaru is, in my opinion, a far better design implementation for forms (and I had no clue it could be done that way).  Then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60203173/4190564) by Reza Aghaei which uses `using assembly` to make types in System.Windows.Forms available.

The code below is a hybrid of the Visual Basic's InputBox layout, Microsoft's Custom Input Box's foundational code, rokumaru's design implementation plus comboBox, and Reza's `using assembly`.

The function Open-SelectBox takes a $Prompt string, $Title string, and $Options which is an array of strings, and opens a VB like InputBox.  The $comboBox is populated with $Options and Open-SelectBox returns either $null if cancel is pressed, an empty string if OK is pressed without selecting anything, or an option provided by $Options.

There is definitely some fine tuning that could be done related to how the comboBox is populated, should it have a default value, should it be forced to only return a valid value, etc... But I feel this is a fairly good foundation code that you should be able to use in your project.

If you need some functionality changed, let me know.

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing

function Open-SelectBox {
    [OutputType([string])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Prompt,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Title,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [string[]]$Options
    )
    $okButton = [Button]@{
        Location = '290,12'
        Size = '60,22'
        Text = 'OK'
        DialogResult = [DialogResult]::OK
    }
    $cancelButton = [Button]@{
        Location = '290,40'
        Size = '60,22'
        Text = 'Cancel'
        DialogResult = [DialogResult]::Cancel
    }
    $label = [Label]@{
        AutoSize = $true
        Location = '10,10'
        Size = '240,20'
        MaximumSize = '250,0'
        Text = $Prompt
    }
    $comboBox =[ComboBox]@{
        Location = '10,90'
        AutoSize = $true
        MaximumSize = '335,0'
        DropDownStyle = "DropDownList"
        ValueMember = "A2"
    }
    $comboBox.Items.AddRange($Options)
    $SelectBox = [form]@{
        Text = $Title
        Size = '369,159'
        StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
        AcceptButton = $okButton
        CancelButton = $cancelButton
        FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
        MinimizeBox  = $false
        MaximizeBox = $false
    }
    $SelectBox.Controls.AddRange(@($okButton, $cancelButton, $label, $comboBox))
    $SelectBox.Topmost = $true
    $SelectBox.Add_Shown({$comboBox.Select()})
    $result = $SelectBox.ShowDialog()
    if ($result -eq [DialogResult]::OK) {
        return $comboBox.Text
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}
$hash = @{
    A1 = "Stick"
    A2 = "Leaf"
    A3 = "Tree"
}
$Key = Open-SelectBox 'Type the name of a computer' 'Test' $hash.Keys
if($null -eq $Key) {
    Write-Host 'Cancel pressed!'
} elseif( '' -eq $Key) {
    Write-Host "Nothing selected!"
} else {
    Write-Host "$($hash[$Key])"
}
```